# Retrieve data from a Form within an Alert Dialog in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

In order for my app's Alert Dialogs to be consistent, I have created a function that returns an **Alert Dialog**. The function does a bit of "painting", to make it look the way I want, but its basic structure is:

```dart
AlertDialog myAlertDialog({
  @required BuildContext context,
  @required Widget myContent,
  @required Function onAccept,}){

  return AlertDialog(
  content: Column(
      children = [
       myContent,
       FlatButton(child: Text("ok"), onPressed: onAccept),
       FlatButton(child: Text("cancel"), onPressed: Navigator.pop(context),
      ]
    )
  );
}
```

In this particular occasion, I am sending a Form to the `myContent` parameter. I am currently stuck on how to retrieve the data from the form in `myContent` and pass it to the function `onAccept`.

In case it might be helpful, the following is the basic structure of my form:

```dart
class myForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _myFormState createState() => _myFormState();
}

class _myFormState extends State<myForm> {
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: ListView(
        children: [
            TextFormField(onChanged: (val) {setState(() {var1 = val;});}, ... ), //Field 1
            TextFormField(onChanged: (val) {setState(() {var2 = val;});}, ... ), //Field 2
            //...
          ],
        ),
   );
 }
}
```

Thanks!

**EDIT**
I noticed the following might also be useful/needed in order for my current problem to be more clear:

This is how I call the `AlertDialog` from the main widget.

```dart
class MainWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FlatButton(
        child: Text("launch Alert Dialog",),
        onPressed: () {showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (BuildContext context) {
                          return _launchAlertDialog(context);
                        },
                      );},
      ),
    );
  }
}

AlertDialog _launchAlertDialog(BuildContext context){
   return myAlertDialog(
     context: context,
     content: myForm(), //Data is captured here
     onAccept: (){}, //But I need to use it here
   );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it as follows:

(Note: it might not be the most elegant solution.. do let me know if there is a better way)

**1)** I created a `Map` that will hold the data.

**2)** I then created a function (called `saveData`) to add data to the `Map`. Then, I shared that function to the form `myForm`.

**3)** This allows me to easily handle the data at `onAccept`. These steps are below:

```
AlertDialog _launchAlertDialog(BuildContext context){
   Map data = {}; //This will hold my data.
   //And this function edits/adds data to the Map.
   void saveData(String variableName, dynamic value){data[variableName] = value;}
   return myAlertDialog(
     context: context,
     content: myForm(saveData: saveData), //Here, I pass the function to the form.
     onAccept: (){print(data['var1']);}, //Now, I can easily handle the data when the user presses accept.
   );
}
```

**4)** Finally, this is how the form `myForm` uses `saveData` to pass data to `data`:

```
class myForm extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function saveData;

  myForm({
    @required this.saveData,
  });

  @override
  _myFormState createState() => _myFormState();
}

class _myFormState extends State<myForm> {
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: ListView(
        children: [
            TextFormField(onChanged: (val) {setState(() {widget.saveData('var1', val);});}, ... ), //Field 1
            TextFormField(onChanged: (val) {setState(() {widget.saveData('var2', val);});}, ... ), //Field 2
            //...
          ],
        ),
   );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you read the method sig for Navigator.pop you will see

```
static void pop<T extends Object?>(BuildContext context, [ T? result ])
```

As you can see from the moths sig you can return two things in pop. context and the result data you want to send back to the previous screen. So something like this would work.

```
Navigator.pop(context, dataVaribleHere);
```

A more explicit definition is available if you are using VSCode and hover over the pop function a hint window will show.

The docs from the hint window:

> void pop(BuildContext context, [T result])
> package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart
>
> Pop the top-most route off the navigator that most tightly encloses
> the given context. The current route's [Route.didPop] method is called
> first. If that method returns false, then the route remains in the
> [Navigator]'s history (the route is expected to have popped some
> internal state; see e.g. [LocalHistoryRoute]). Otherwise, the rest of
> this description applies.
>
> **If non-null, result will be used as the result of the route that is
> popped; the future that had been returned from pushing the popped
> route will complete with result. Routes such as dialogs or popup menus
> typically use this mechanism to return the value selected by the user
> to the widget that created their route. The type of result, if
> provided, must match the type argument of the class of the popped
> route (T).**
>
> The popped route and the route below it are notified (see
> [Route.didPop], [Route.didComplete], and [Route.didPopNext]). If the
> [Navigator] has any [Navigator.observers], they will be notified as
> well (see [NavigatorObserver.didPop]).
>
> The T type argument is the type of the return value of the popped
> route.
>
> The type of result, if provided, must match the type argument of the
> class of the popped route (T).

You will need to catch the data in your screen that is pushing the alert dialog.
Something like this. Notice that the containing function that it showing the dialog is an async function. This is important it lets us us the `await` keyword to wait for the dialog to dismiss before processing.

```
_showMyDialog() async {
var result = await showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (_) => new AlertDialog(
          title: new Text("Material Dialog"),
          content: new Text("Hey! I'm Coflutter!"),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('Close me!'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context, dataVaribleHere);
              },
            )
          ],
        ));
          if (result != null) {
            setState(() {
              //Do stuff
            });
          }
  }
```

You will need to adapt this code to your specific situation but it shows the basic  idea. Note that this code will not run as is. This will teach you how it's not for copy/pasting. dataVaribleHere is not a real variable it's telling you where to put your data.

Comment: thanks, I appreciate it. Your solution seems very useful in order to get data out of an `AlertDialog`. However, my current problem is how to get the data out of the Form in `myForm()` and use it on the function `onAccept`. I just edited my question and added a bit of extra info to try to make this more clear. In particular, please see the comments in the code. Please let me know if it makes sense.

Comment: You are using showDialog just like my example. Please read it again. All the information you need is in my answer. showDialog -> new screen -> return to old screen with new data.

Comment: I'll take a closer look tomorrow and let you know. Thanks man.

Comment: I think where you might be confused is that showDialog takes a Widget. Any widget. give it myForm instead of myAlertDialog in the builder. No need to nest it inside.

Comment: Why are you trying to use the data at myAlertDialog level? I would expect you want to use it on the original screen?

Comment: When you take a look tomorrow let me know if you truly want to access the data in the showDialog? If so I can give an example. It's just not what I expected at all from you original question.

Comment: I just posted the solution that worked for me. Thanks for your help though. Note that the problem wasn't how to get data out of the `AlertDialog`, but how to get it out of the `Form` in the first place. Regarding your suggestion about passing `myForm` to `showDialog` instead of passing `myAlertDialog`, I needed to use `myAlertDialog` because it already had the "look-and-feel" of my app. Finally, I agree that I could have phrased my question better. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Not radically different from your own solution but it leverages the internal saving mechanism of `Form` so it's less of a workaround. I have the following helper function to make it easier to use form dialogs from anywhere:

```
Future<bool> inputFormDialog(BuildContext context, {String? title, required Form Function(BuildContext, GlobalKey) formBuilder, String? okButton, String? cancelButton}) async {
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final result = await showDialog<bool>(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false,
    builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
      title: (title != null) ? Text(title) : null,
      content: formBuilder(context, formKey),
      actions: [
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, false),
          child: Text(cancelButton?.toUpperCase() ?? MaterialLocalizations.of(context).cancelButtonLabel),
        ),
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
              formKey.currentState!.save();
              Navigator.pop(context, true);
            }
          },
          child: Text(okButton?.toUpperCase() ?? MaterialLocalizations.of(context).okButtonLabel),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
  return result ?? false;
}
```

As you can see, it has some creature comforts as title, standard buttons with either standard or provided names. The small difference to your solution is that it handles the form state autonomically and calls the validation and saving functions when required. It can be used like this:

```
if (await inputFormDialog(context, formBuilder: (context, formKey) => buildFormDialog(context, formKey))) {
  setState(() {
    // handle the data set by the form innards, eg. formVariable
  });
}
```

where the form builder is a usual builder function:

```
Form buildFormDialog(BuildContext context, GlobalKey formKey) {
  return Form(
    key: formKey,
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        TextFormField(
          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
          decoration: ...,
          validator: ...,
          onSaved: (value) => formVariable = value!,
        ),
        // ...
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```